# Python: sample n numbers from sorted array making sure that they are as far away as possible from each other

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say that I have the following array:

```
myarr = np.array([0, 4, 3, 6, 12, 9, 17, 86])
```

and that I need to sample `n>=2` numbers from this array such that their difference represents the maximum difference possible. In my example, I would first sort the array smallest to largest:

```
myarr_s = np.sort(myarr) = array([0, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 17, 86])
```

Now, if `n=2`, my choice would be `0, 86`, because their difference is the maximum difference possible in the array. I am looking for a pythonic way of doing this in situations where `n>2`.

To give you a further example, if my array was `np.arange(0,101,1)` and `n=5`, my choices would have to be `0, 25, 50, 75, 100`.

Comment: why isn't the result of your second example `0, 33, 66, 99`? My feeling is that you need to work a bit more on your definition of the problem; make it mathematically more precise. As it now stands, it is not clear what you are asking, at least not to me.

Comment: @Ma0 well spotted - see the updated version.

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of splitting the sorted array to `n - 1` equal parts, then picking the edges of each part?

Comment: It is not clear how you define difference. If sum of differences in sorted order then diff([0, 25, 50, 75, 100]) = 25 * 4 = diff([0, 26, 50, 75, 100])

Comment: @V.Ayrat prob not the sum OR avg of differences. Maybe OP is trying to maximize the minimum difference between numbers.

Comment: @DeepSpace I don't think that would work. For the array `array([0, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 17, 86])`, if `n=3` the answer should be `0, 17, 86` not `0, 9, 86`, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @ywbaek almost there. I am trying to maximize the difference between numbers.

Comment: @Zizzipupp You need to clarify more. your output has multiple differences for `n>2` and it is not a single number to be maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the sorted array to n-1 equal parts and pick the edges. Then find the closest numbers to those edges in your array

```
def foo(a, n): 
     _a = np.sort(a) 
     ret = np.zeros(n) 
     ret[0], ret[-1] = _a[0], _a[-1] 
     if n==2: 
         return ret 
     midvals = [ret[0]+i*(ret[-1]-ret[0])/(n-1) for i in range(1, n-1)] 
     def closest(arr, val): 
         diff = [abs(v-val) for v in arr] 
         return arr[np.argmin(diff)] 
     for i,v in enumerate(midvals): 
         ret[i+1] = closest(a, v) 
     return ret
```

Comment: `foo([0, 4, 3, 6, 12, 9, 17, 86], 4)` gives me `array([ 0., 17., 86., 86.])`, which is not correct (if I understood the question correctly)